# Microcontroller system or PLC system

Tags: circuit-analysis, sensor, analog, raspberry-pi, plc

I am a software engineer ,Recently I have completed an industrial project using raspberry pi and some other components .
The project essentially is to measure pressure(pressure sensor)and displacement(rotary encoder) and plot a **Realtime Graph** using the sensor outputs which are placed on a machine.
Now one of the customers (B2B model) suggested that this project can be done using a **PLC** and could be done in low cost .

**Questions** :

1)Is it posiible and viable to use PLC for a standalone machine just for two sensors?

2)I had to write a total software for this project which would take data, plot output graph and perform various calculations using the graph ,is it replacable by PLC software ?

Comment: Only you know the details of your project, so make sure you [read about PLCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller) and make a judgement. Reading between the lines, it sounds like the customer thinks you've charged too much. At the end of the day, most of the cost of many (not all) projects is man-hours. In these cases, it all boils down to what you're familiar with, which drives how long it would take. Add in the man-hours for you to climb the PLC learning curve and see if that would have ended up any "cheaper" for the customer.

Comment: It sounds like your project includes a significant amount of HMI (Human Machine Interface) functionality. There are certainly PLCs that could do that. PLCs are generally more suitable for an industrial project than hobby open-PCBs and by the time you ruggedize such bits and write software that *may* be easier on a PLC you may end up spending more and ending up with less reliable or maintainable hardware. My main concern would be whether the hardware met all the stated and implied requirements. For example, can you ensure that the RPi always shuts down gracefully?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  Yes !! i have ensured that rpi shuts down each and every time the task /job is done also i have added the ESD protection circit to it . Most important thing is that by using graphs library i have got graph that are literally textbook perfect . The basic things that i need were Realtime Graphs,calculations based on graph results,Graph manipulation after tasks etc .

Comment: A PLC with high speed analogue input and a HMI would cost a lot. However raspberry pi is not a solution for industrial environment.  As an automation engineer, I wouldn't buy your product with RPi. The best solution would be a custom board with galvanically isolated analogue input, optocoupled inputs for encoder, 24VDC power supply.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy some quite dumb PLCs, that will only handle a few inputs, outputs and lines of ladder logic, and some really quite clever ones, that *are* a Pi class or better processor inside, with storage and a nice GUI.

A PLC is a product that is targeted to a very specific and limited application space, it's not a general purpose computer.

The advantage of a PLC is it's 'industry ready', already in a tough box with protected I/Os, and easy to duplicate if you need more systems.

The problem with a PLC is whether it provides an adequate API, or whether you can 'get into' the software to do what you want. You may find an interface that's been crippled to do exactly what it's advertised to do and no more. I know my TV recorder is just a processor running Linux inside, but I can't get it to do more than the interface presents (won't copy MP3s from a USB for instance) without nuking it and installing a bare OS.

The question is, do you want to ruggedise a Pi, or find a PLC that you can have your wicked way with?

Comment: Well i have tried my best to Ruggedize the pi (shuts down correctly ,used and ESD protection ckt . The things that i needed for this project are Realtime Graphs,calculations based on graph results,Graph manipulation after tasks , different types of graphs based on user inputs and ofcourse a beautiful UI which is done perfectly using rpi . I have put in much effort to  build this but i was wodering if there was this alternate way in which someone would make a similar product using PLC for lesser price . It seems from answers that there are infact some constraints of using a PLC as well !

Answer (score 2):

PLC:s make sense for low volume projects, where high cost of a few units is acceptable. The typical example is factory automation.

For high volume, cost-sensitive projects, a microcontroller should be used. A microcontroller solution on a custom PCB is approximately 10 to 20 times cheaper than a PLC.

But to do this, you need at least one professional firmware programmer and one professional electronics designer. That is, you need more skilled personnel, the development time will be longer and cost more, but the end product will be cheap and completely customized to its designated task.

You could of course use some pre-made board like Raspberry, but it isn't likely going to be perfectly suitabe and adapted to the specific project.

For the PLC solution, you would need a PLC programmer - programming a PLC and a microcontroller are quite different things. PLC programming is mostly about learning a specific tool chain.